# how to use 32-bit registers in emu8086 with fasm assembler

Tags: assembly

first of all you should know that my knowledge of the assembly language is very limited you must be very thorough in your answer.
I just wanna know how can I use 32-bit register in my assembly code?!

currently when want to use the EAX or EBX ,... register it throws an error that says it is undefined!
thank you in advance... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`emu8086`, as its name implies, emulates [8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) chips. Those are 16bit. They do not have 32bit registers. So you can't use `EAX` and related with that emulator.

Comment: that's too bad. can u suggest another assembler that supports 32-bit registers?

Comment: @2hamed: Basically any other assembler.  Good free ones include NASM and FASM, and the GNU assembler is widely used.  (They're *just* assemblers, not IDEs + simulators.  You could use them with Bochs or DOSBox, or to make 32-bit or 64-bit code for modern OSes.)